# how filters short-circuit request pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core MVC, just a question on how filters short-circuit request pipeline. I know that setting filter's context.Result will bypass/short-circuit the request pipeline. Below is a scree shot from my textbook:

[image]

Let's say I have the following statement in an Action Filter:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
   context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);
}
```

my questions are:

Q1-That means the action method will no be invoked, but how does it actually happen, there must be sth that checks `context.Result` to determine if the action method should be invoked. so what's this thing?

Q2- Does result filters still apply after the request has been short-circuited?

Q3- if result filters won't apply, how the IActionResult Execution get invoked?

Answer (score 1):

This clearly indicates that setting the `Result` short-circuits the action and the pipeline, such that no other action filter can run:

- [ActionExecutingContext.Result Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionexecutingcontext.result?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ActionExecutingContext_Result)

> Setting Result to a non-null value inside an action filter will short-circuit the action and any remaining action filters.

Now, an `IResultFilter` or `IAsyncResultFilter` are only called if the action method (or an action filter) produces a result, which is in your case true. They won't be called if your action method or action filter bubbles up an exception. See:

- [IResultFilter and IAsyncResultFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters)